# Closure in grails controller not picking up arguments

Tags: grails, groovy, closures

I'm trying to consolidate redundant code in my controller using a utility closure to do generic exception handler and response generation.

For instance, I want to consolidate this:

```groovy
def newUser(){
  def model = [:]
  def errors

  try{
     model += [newUserObj:dao.newUser(...)]
  }catch(Exception e){
     errors = e.getMessage()
  }
  renderJson(model,error)
}
```

..to this:

```groovy
def newUser(){
  def model = [:]
  def errors
  doRequest(model, errors){ ->
     model += [newUserObj:dao.newUser(...)]
  }
}
```

..while moving boilerplate code to a closure:

```groovy
def doRequest(model, errors, clsr){
  try{
     clsr.call()
  }catch(Exception e){
     errors = e.getMessage()
  }
  //!! model here is null !!
  renderJson(model,error)
}
```

The problem happens in `doRequest()` when `renderJson()` is invoked; `model` is null, even though I confirmed it's assigned correctly inside the closure at  `model += [newUserObj:dao.newUser(...)]`.

### Workaround

I managed to get around this issue by just returning the `model` from the closure:

```groovy
def newUser(){
  doRequest(){ ->
     def model = [:]
     def errors
     model += [newUserObj:dao.newUser(...)]
     [model:model, errors:errors]
  }
}

def doRequest(clsr){
  def model = [:]
  def errors
  try{
     def r = clsr.call()
     model = r['model']
     errors = r['errors']
  }catch(Exception e){
     errors = e.getMessage()
  }
  renderJson(model,error)
}
```

..but this doesn't seem Groovy at all, I'm creating boiler plate code I was trying to avoid in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
import grails.converters.JSON

//Closure implementation
def doRequest(Closure clsr) {
    def model = [:]
    def errors = /No Error Message Yet/

    try {
        model = clsr(model)
    } catch(Exception e) {
        errors = e.getMessage()
    }

    renderJson(model, errors)
}

//Mimics an action method
def newUser() {
    doRequest { model ->
        model += [a:1] //Mimics the call to DAO in your question

        //make sure to return the model after all operations completed
        //model
    }
}

//Mimics the render to JSON utility
private JSON renderJson(model, error) {
    [model: model, errors: error] as JSON
}

//Mimics call to the action method
assert newUser().toString() == 
                              /{"model":{"a":1},"errors":"No Error Message Yet"}/
```

I could have implemented `doRequest()` something as below, but I did not because in that case model and errors would become part of the class (in your case it will be Controller's global properties) which we do not want.

```
def doRequest(Closure clsr) {
    try {
        clsr.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        clsr.delegate = this

        clsr()
    } catch(Exception e) {
        errors = e.getMessage()
    }

    renderJson(model, errors)
}
```